# Can’t boot Windows after installing Xubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, uefi

I’ve attempted to do a dual boot set up of Windows 10 and Xubuntu, but now I’m incapable of booting Windows 10.

- Windows partition still exists
- When attempting to boot Windows from BIOS, it instead boots Xubuntu
- Have attempted boot repair and GRUB update, encounter issue regarding Legacy Windows
- When attempting to boot from Xubuntu live in non UEFI mode to counteract this, I get a black screen

I’m told that the issue (at this stage) is that live linux is failing to start in graphics mode.

Worth noting is that when initially attempting to install Xubuntu, I encountered some kind of “fatal error” and was told the install failed. Regardless, my system boots to Xubuntu.

Computer is HP Spectre ap012dx. Xubuntu is latest version. Brand new flash drive with 32 gigs.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have one OS on legacy boot, and the other OS on uefi boot. You need to get both of them on one or the other. Try running Boot Repair from a  linux usb https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: as mentioned in the post, i’ve done so already and encounter an error because the pc is not in UEFI, “legacywindows detected” i can’t run the linux live in the nesscesary mode (non UEFI) because when doing so, I get a black screen.

Comment: I got it now. When you said boot repair, you indeed meant the famous Boot Repair tool. I think I had this exact issue once. You could try running the Macrium Reflect rescue media (or other rescue media if you like). Reflect  has a free version, and you could install it on a different Windows machine so you can create the bootable rescue media. That will fix your Windows boot. Then, convert your Windows installation to efi https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-legacy-bios-uefi-windows10/ and afterward you will probably need to reinstall grub from a live linux media.

Comment: unfortunately, i don’t have another windows machine available. does this make your solution null?

Comment: So from within Xubuntu, remove (delete) grub, and edit your boot partition so that there are no linux entries in it. Follow these instructions. You can do it from your real linux system, you don't need a live usb for this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi Then you should be able to boot into Windows, either automatically or from BIOS, and continue from there. I am assuming you have windows 10, because converting earlier versions of windows is not so easy.